# pip install mysqlclient does'nt work on linux host

Tags: mysql, django, database, cpanel, host

Now i upload my project into the linux host (shared hosting) and install my packages with host terminal 
after this when i want runserver this error doesn't allow me for complete uploading
I using django and mysql database and my host system is linux 
when I run

`pip install mysqlclient`

this error show off :

```
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/mahdiade/virtualenv/portfolio/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-89jdmhun/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-89jdmhun/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-e3zg78wq --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-89jdmhun/mysqlclient/  Complete output (30 lines):  /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/mahdiade/virtualenv/portfolio/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-89jdmhun/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-89jdmhun/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-p43_gxw8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mahdiade/virtualenv/portfolio/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-89jdmhun/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/mahdiade/virtualenv/portfolio/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-89jdmhun/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-89jdmhun/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-p43_gxw8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mahdiade/virtualenv/portfolio/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

what's the problem?

I search in the internet but couldn't solve this problem

Comment: `unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied` implies that `gcc` is not installed or somehow wasn't installed correctly.

Comment: @tadman how can i fixed this???? Can i solve this problem or my host company can solve it????

Comment: I'd take it up with your hosting provider if they can lend a hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu you should install build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: I can't use sudo apt-get because shared hosting don't allow me, I have access to a number of features under jaishell , for sudo apt-get I must have virtual server, now for this do you have solution???? do you know database that doesn't have this problem????